# Is there way to commit based on last modification time of a project folder/file?

Tags: git

I am trying to add an existing C project to git. However, the last time I worked on this project was around a year back. If I initialize the existing project repository using the following,

`git init && git add . && git commit -m "Hello World"`

the commit date will be set to the current date.

Is it possible to set the commit date (the initial commit) based on the last modification time of the project folder/files ?

**Update:** Included previous updates as part of the answer to the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of the question:
"Is it possible to set the commit date (the initial commit) based on the last modification time of the project folder/files ?"

From [@JamesJJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11378995/jamesjj) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56333930/10155936), I have come up with sequence of commands

```
git init
git add .
ls --full-time --time-style=long-iso | sort -r | awk '{if(NR==2)print $6"T"$7}' | xargs git commit -m "Hello World" --date
```

- To commit based on last modification time of the project directory (provided current directory is the project directory),

```
export temp=`ls --full-time --time-style=long-iso -d . | awk '{print $6"T"$7}'`
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Commit Message" --date $temp
unset temp
```

- To commit based on last modification time of the project files/sub-directories,

```
git init
git add .
ls --full-time --time-style=long-iso | awk '{if(NR != 1) print $6"T"$7}' | sort -r | head -n 1 | xargs git commit -m "Commit Message" --date
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use `--date` when you commit, for example:
`git commit -m "Hello World" --date "2005-04-07T22:13:13"`

Comment: How about using this command ? ```ls --full-time --time-style=long-iso | sort -r | awk '{if(NR==2)print $6,$7}'```  One can obtain the most recent date and possibly use xargs with the git command above ?